# Additional Moderator Needed

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally Moderators are elected by the community, but until this site reaches a critical mass to hold an election, I need to appoint another provisional Moderators to help moderate this site.

Please nominate some folks you might like to see become the provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide some valuable support to help us make our selection. You can read more about the process here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

## The Nomination Process:

- Nominate a user by adding an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity. I added a short template (below) to help you with that process.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- Nominations can include links to other activities: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **The nominee should indicate their acceptance** by editing the answer (not commenting) to say they accept. Optionally, nominees are encouraged to write a bit about themselves following the nomination. You can use the `---` markup to separate the nominee's commentary from the original nomination. See the example below.

## Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are seeking out members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active in the site's activities;
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities;
- Leads by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write;
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Here is an example nomination entry. You can copy-and-paste from the format below:

> ```
> <h2>[username](<main profile link>) </h2>
>
> <h2>[Meta Profile](<meta profile link>) </h2>
>
> Notes:
>
> <why you feel nominee would be a useful addition to the pro tem choices>
>
> ---
> ```
>
> <sup><sup>(this section is edited in by the nominee)</sup></sup>
>
> ```
> I accept/decline this nomination
>
> I am name/age/location/fun fact/all optional. I live in location, so I am 
> generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may 
> want to know about me are…
>
> etc.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to nominate https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/225/aidan

Aidan is regularly active in the community here on civicrm.stackexchange.com as well as in the CiviCRM Mattermost chat community at https://chat.civicrm.org.

---

I accept this nomination.

I am Aidan Saunders of Squiffle Consulting, a CiviCRM Partner. I am based in the UK and often on here during UK daytime hours.

Comment: Just emailed you, @Aidan.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to also nominate @xavier as a fourth moderator. @aidan and @petednz-fuzion both agree that it would be a good addition. @xavier has a long history with the CiviCRM community including significant work on the API back in the day, and leading the Google Summer of Code administration for several years now, as well as developing a good reputation answering questions here on SE.